# How can I convert a float type data set with missing data to int?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

```
print(movie_idname['rating'])
```

I would like to convert that into all int numbers, these are some of the codes I have tried :

```
for rating in movie_idname:
    if rating == float:
        int_rating = movie_idname['rating'].astype(int)
        print(int_rating)
        break
```

#### received no error but does not work

```
int_rating = movie_idname['rating'].astype(int)
```

#### ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4.0'

--> this is how the data set for rating looks like 
print(movie_idname['rating'])

```
0        4.0
1        5.0
2        5.0
3        4.0
4        4.0
        ... 
82624    3.0
82625    4.5
82626    4.0
82627    5.0
82628    4.5
Name: rating, Length: 82629, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a series of *strings* (hence your output says `dtype: object`) which look like floats. Those can't be converted directly to int, but you can do it if you convert to float along the way:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.Series(["1.0", "2.5"])
0    1.0
1    2.5
dtype: object
>>> pd.Series(["1.0", "2.5"]).astype(int)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.0'
>>> pd.Series(["1.0", "2.5"]).astype(float)
0    1.0
1    2.5
dtype: float64
>>> pd.Series(["1.0", "2.5"]).astype(float).astype(int)
0    1
1    2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

What you did should work. Are you forgetting to take a look at int_rating? You are not assigning it back to the dateframe, like `movie_idname['int_rating'] = ...`.

Try this, for instance:

```
import pandas as pd
from random import uniform

movie_idname = pd.DataFrame({
    'rating': [uniform(0, 10) for _ in range(100)]
})

print(movie_idname)

      rating
0   6.032252
1   0.492256
2   7.474722
3   0.175150
4   7.286012
..       ...
95  1.385851
96  9.070880
97  7.222838
98  4.941222
99  1.443023

movie_idname['rating_int'] = movie_idname['rating'].astype(int)
print(movie_idname)

      rating  rating_int
0   6.032252           6
1   0.492256           0
2   7.474722           7
3   0.175150           0
4   7.286012           7
..       ...         ...
95  1.385851           1
96  9.070880           9
97  7.222838           7
98  4.941222           4
99  1.443023           1
```

Comment: Great! If I answered your question please click the gray checkmark on the left side of this answer to mark it as accepted.